How to load LoRA weights for image classification model
I trained a model like below.
model_name = 'owkin/phikon'
model = AutoModelForImageClassification.from_pretrained(
    model_name,
    label2id=label2id,
    id2label=id2label,
    ignore_mismatched_sizes=False,
    cache_dir=cache_dir,
)

from peft import LoraConfig, get_peft_model, PeftConfig, PeftModel


config = LoraConfig(
    r=16,
    lora_alpha=16,
    target_modules=["query", "value"],
    lora_dropout=0.1,
    bias="none",
    modules_to_save=["classifier"],
)
lora_model = get_peft_model(model, config)

import numpy as np
import torch

import evaluate
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer

# LoRA configuration
#lora_model = model
save_name = 'custom_training_2'
batch_size = 128 if "v2" not in model_name else 32
args = TrainingArguments(
    save_name,
    remove_unused_columns=False,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    save_strategy="steps",
    learning_rate=5e-3,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=1,
    per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
    fp16=True,
    seed=SEED,
    num_train_epochs=10,
    logging_steps=1,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model="accuracy",  # dataset is roughly balanced
    push_to_hub=False,
    label_names=["labels"],
    save_steps = 10,

)

# Metric configuration

metric = evaluate.load("accuracy")

def compute_metrics(eval_pred: np.ndarray) -> float:
    """Computes accuracy on a batch of predictions."""
    predictions = np.argmax(eval_pred.predictions, axis=1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=eval_pred.label_ids)

# Inputs generation for training

def collate_fn(examples) -> dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
    """Create the inputs for LoRA from an example in the dataset."""
    pixel_values = torch.stack([example["pixel_values"] for example in examples])
    labels = torch.tensor([example["label"] for example in examples])
    return {"pixel_values": pixel_values, "labels": labels}

# Here is the final trainer
trainer_lora = Trainer(
    model=lora_model,
    args=args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    tokenizer=image_processor,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    data_collator=collate_fn,
)

# Here is for fully training the model.

import warnings

from transformers.utils import logging

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)
    train_results_lora = trainer_lora.train()
    metrics_lora = trainer_lora.evaluate(test_dataset)
    trainer_lora.log_metrics("Trained model: VAL-CRC-7K", metrics_lora)


At the end of training, I obtain a folder like below
--\runs
--\checkpoint-10
--\checkpoint-20
----adapter_config.json
----adapter_model.safetensors
----optimizer.pt
----preprocessor_config.json
----README.md   
----rng_state.pth
----scheduler.pt
----trainer_state.json
----training_args.bin

My question is that: how can I load trained weights for inference?
I found these solutions but did not work for me:
How to load LoRA weights saved locally?
https://pypi.org/project/lora-pytorch/
https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/loading-lora-models-after-trainning/74076
